# How do I sign my ProGuard'ed Scala stand-alone JARs?

Tags: java, scala, jar, proguard, sbt

I've built a (command-line) application in Scala that I want to distribute as a standalone JAR. I'm building it with sbt:

```
import sbt._

class Project(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info) with ProguardProject {
  override def parallelExecution = true      
  override def mainClass: Option[String] = // whatever

  override def libraryDependencies = Set(
    // whatever
  ) ++ super.libraryDependencies

  override def proguardOptions = List(
      "-keepclasseswithmembers public class * { public static void main(java.lang.String[]); }",
      "-dontoptimize",
      "-dontobfuscate",
      proguardKeepLimitedSerializability,
      proguardKeepAllScala,
      "-keep interface scala.ScalaObject"
  )
}
```

I can run my code with `sbt run` fine, and I can package it and run ProGuard over it (I'm not interested in obfuscating - the project is going to be open source anyway), I'm just using it to produce a standalone JAR). So, I eventually get a .min.jar file built in target/scala_2.8.0/

This is where it gets complicated. If I run this JAR, I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Okay, I haven't signed it.

So, I generate myself a signing key as follows:

```
keytool -keystore ~/.keystore -genkey -alias tom
```

And then, following the Java documentation, I try to sign the JAR:

```
jarsigner -signedjar [whatever].jar -keystore ~/.keystore target/scala_2.8.0/[whatever]-1.0.min.jar tom
```

It prompts me:

```
Enter Passphrase for keystore: 

Warning: 
The signer certificate will expire within six months.
```

Okay, that's fine. Now, surely, it'll run!

```
$ java -jar [whatever].jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
```

I have no idea where to begin. I'm relatively new to the Java platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need ProGuard and signing to produce a standalone jar. You can just pack all the classes you need and a META-INF directory with proper classpath and main class set in a zip file, rename it to jar and it should run. See [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html).

Sorry, I didn't answer your question, I just don't understand why you want to sign your jar.

Comment: I think the issue is that jars normally can't contain jars, if I remember correctly, while ProGuard creates jars that can.

Comment: I see, so he just needs to unpack scala-library.jar into his jar?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and it appears the problem was that sun's jar signatures were added by proguard in the META-INF directory. I just added them to the filtered files:

```
override def makeInJarFilter (file :String) =
  super.makeInJarFilter(file) + ",!**/SUN_MICR.RSA,!**/SUN_MICR.SF"
```

and it works perfectly now.